# dataframe parameters: Why do the changes on my df are local?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that is supposed to implement some transformations and calculations on a df, the code runs but once it's done df remains the same as before.

EDIT: The problem is solved when I remove the line 2 (pd.merge), but I'd like to understand why.

```py
def Tilt_contribution(ptf, data_factors, data_universe, Sample_size_adjustment:bool):
    ptf['ActiveWeight'] = ptf['PortfolioWeight']- ptf['BenchmarkWeight']
    ptf = pd.merge(ptf, data_factors, on = ['ISIN','SecurityName'], how = 'left' )
    sample_size_adj = 1 #initialisation
    if Sample_size_adjustment == True:
        sample_size_adj = Sample_size_adj(ptf)
    for column in factor_list:
        #Weighted std
        universe_wght_std = Universe_weighted_std(data_universe, column)
        #Benchmark weighted average
        benchmk_wght_avg = Benchmark_weighted_avg(ptf, column)
        #Tilt Contrib   
        col_index = ptf.columns.get_loc(column)
        ptf.insert(col_index+1, column + ' Tilt Contribution', 0)    
        for idx in ptf.index:
            tilt_cont = (ptf.at[idx, column] - benchmk_wght_avg)*ptf.at[idx, 'ActiveWeight']/(sample_size_adj * universe_wght_std)
            if math.isnan(tilt_cont):
                tilt_cont=0
            ptf.at[idx, column + ' Tilt Contribution'] = tilt_cont
    global Tilt
    Tilt = ptf.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the global var `Tilt` with the sum of `ptf` but not returning the modified `ptf` DataFrame.

Comment: But how come, in other functions the changes applied to the df are global without the need to return it